# Error while trying to use Sax Parser on xhtml file

Tags: java, xml, xhtml, saxparser, malformedurlexception

I'm trying to parse an xhml file using SAXParser in Java, but gets an exception:

> "java.net.MalformedURLException:
>   unknown protocol: g"

The line made that exception was:

```
SAXBuilder.build(Destination)
```

While Destination is the full path to the xhml file.
The beginning of the xhml file is as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="../article.css" type="text/css"?>
<div id="article" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

While div is the root element.

I tried to look for documentation over the web about protocol g or MalformedURLException,
i tried to play with the namespaces as well, but couldn't get this work.

Does anyone have any idea what can i do to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to give us the whole file, since it's probable that you have a `href="g:something"` or `src="g:something"` somewhere in your file. Doesn't the exception tell you which line in the XML file contains the malformed URL?

Comment: What exactly does "Destination" hold? It sounds like perhaps SAXBuilder is treating as a URL not a local path.

Comment: Great! Thanks Matthew!! Probably this time - the SAX parser treated the parameter it gets as a URL and not as a File as always (because it is a xhtml file...).

Comment: Instantiating a new File with the 'Destination' path solved the whole problem.

Comment: I guess I should turn the comment into an answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Based on discussion in the comments) SAXBuilder is treating "Destination" as a URL and not a local file. Call "build" with a File object instead.